# Limit controls must follow a math operator error

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am using the following equation but getting an error "Limit controls must follow a math operator"

```
$\Upsilon = \text{Hypergeometric}\sideset{_2}{_1}F\Bigl(1+d,2+d+m,2+d,\frac{-A\sigma^2_{f_r}}{B\sigma^2_{f_e}\gamma_s} \Bigr)$
```

Any help to remove this error will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want just `{}_2F_1` instead of `\sideset`.

Comment: Ok...Thank You...

Comment: You should also use `\mathrm{Hypergeometric}` not `\text{...}`. Why, `\itshape test $\text{test}$ text` (not what you'd expect)

Comment: oK... Thank you sir..